# Implementation of Singleton Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I have implemented singleton pattern in javascript.

it is has follows,

```
var Student = (function(){
    var obj = {};
    return {
        getInstance : function(){
            return obj;
        }
    }
})();

var student1 = Student.getInstance();

student1.name = "Mejam Kinavchisko";

var student2 = Student.getInstance();
student2.age = 23;

console.log(student1.name);
console.log(student2.name);
console.log(student2.age);
console.log(student1.age);
```

The output is as follows,

```
Mejam Kinavchisko
Mejam Kinavchisko
23
23
```

In the above example you can see for a given instance if I add a new property "name" and assign
some value, same is been reflected in the other instance.

i.e. student1 and student2 are pointing to same object.

Hence I wont to know that if I have achieved Singleton Pattern in javascript ?

Comment: Same value is reflected because objects are passed by reference. So in reality, `Stugent.getInstanceOf` will return a location and then you override object at that location

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? A simple `Yes / No`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Singleton pattern is thus known because it restricts instantiation of a class to a single object. Classically, the Singleton pattern can be implemented by creating a class with a method that creates a new instance of the class if one doesn't exist. In the event of an instance already existing, it simply returns a reference to that object.

The reference of both the objects created here is the same, thereby the `Singleton` behaviour.

For a detailed idea about the topic you should read [Addy Osmani's guide to Javascript Design Patterns.](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is singleton pattern that's why student1 and student2 are pointing to same object.

For information refer
http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern